# filling a map (dictionary) with dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dictionary

In Java and Python, I found working with maps and dictionaries a very convenient way to handle different dataframes at once. Being a R-newbie, I tried to use this approach to store "parts" of one big dataframe, which I am indexing by using the values ("intervals") from the tlist. To my surprise, the following code did not work and I do not find a solution why:

```
library(hash)
df <- read.csv("(/testfile.csv")
tlist <- list(5, 30, 60, 90, 180, 356)

data_map <- hash() 
for(t in 2:length(tlist)){
data_map[[paste0("T", t)]] <- df[df$T >= tlist[[t-1]]  & df$T <= tlist[[t]], ]
}

data_map[["T1"]] #calling dataframe t1 out of the map
```

When calling the elements of my data_map as in the last line, I get null and I don't understand why. Can anyone give me some insight why filling a hash in this particular matter does not work? Any help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want a hash? Most of the times lists are enough. You can use something like this.

```
tlist <- c(5, 30, 60, 90, 180, 356)
data_map <- vector('list', length(tlist)-1)

for(t in seq_along(tlist)[-1]) {
  data_map[[t-1]] <- df[df$T >= tlist[t-1]  & df$T <= tlist[t], ]
}
```

then access individual values with `data_map[[1]]`, `data_map[[2]]` etc.

You can assign names with

```
names(data_map) <- paste0('T', seq_along(data_map))
```

Comment: I see your point. But lets say I would have a second (nested) loop, looping through the new "slist". In the end, I would like to call some list element with the command data_map[["T1S3"]] . Then this approach to dynamically name my list wouldn't work, right?

Comment: We can change the code based on what you want. You can name your list elements inside the loop or there might also be better approaches. You haven't actually shared any data so it is difficult to give you accurate suggestions.